# Why oracle do not store Bean Validation API?

Tags: java, validation, persistence

Where can I find javax.validation source code?

Where can I find javax.persistence source code?

I think this pages only have the specification/documentation:

https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=349

How can I say that one repository is more reliable than other?

Comment: I found https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final and this http://beanvalidation.org/ too.

Answer (score 0):

JSR 303 is the specification for the Java API for JavaBean validation. There are several reference implementations that implement this specification (and implement the interfaces in the javax.validation package). Hibernate Validator (otherwise unrelated to the Hibernate ORM framework) is one such implementation.

The Java Persistence API (JPA) is another such Java API specification for which several reference implementations exist (e.g. Hibernate ORM, OpenJPA).

If you check the application server you are running your application in, you will find which reference implementation will be used.

Comment: Thank for your answer. Tell me other thing. Are you saying that the javax.validation package just have interfaces?
Does not have "public class Xpto {...}"?

Comment: Take a look at the following link: [http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/ValidatorFactory.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/ValidatorFactory.html) This package contains mostly interfaces and only one public class (_Validation_). The _Validation_ class can be used to get an instance of a _ValidatorFactory_, which will be implemented by one of the reference implementations (denoted as a 'provider'). You can choose to get the default provider, or specify a strategy to select the specific provider you want.